# Jquery for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a paragraph with some words written in span, which is editable once you click on it.The content would be dynamically called so my current approach is not working. Can you suggest me a solution or a better way to do it?
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9dq2p7dw/109/
Thanks :)

```
 <h4>Currently working in <span class="editor">xyz*</span><span style= 
"display:none;" class="edit"><input type="text" class="form-control input-
 sm" id="edited" style="width:100px;z-index: 100;background: white;display: 
  inline;"></span><button type="submit" id="submit" class="edit" 
  style="display: none;">save</button>


      for past <span>0-5 years*</span>.Studied Graduation from <span>ABC.</span>, 12th from <span>jnnj</span> with <span>80%</span>, 10th from <span>Bkbjkjnk</span> with <span>80%</span></h4>
```

and here is the jquery for it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bizcontent').click(function(){
      $('#myModal2').modal('toggle');

    });

    $(".editor").click(function(){
      $(".edit").show();
      $(".editor").hide();
      var edit = $("#edited").val();



    });

    $("#submit").click(function(){
      var edit = $("#edited").val();
      var ans = confirm("Update your input as "+ edit + " ?");

      if (ans== true) {

      $(".edit").hide();
      $(".editor").replaceWith("<span class='editor'>" + edit + "</span>");
      $(".editor").show();

    }

    else{
      $(".editor").show();
      $(".edit").hide();
    }


    });
});
```

Comment: What is not working? What result do you want?

Comment: I want it to work for all the span elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it in the following manner.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // how the input and the text should be displayed
  // {{text}} is replaced with the text
  var template = {
    input: '<edit><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width:100px;display:inline;" value="{{text}}" orig="{{text}}"/><button type="submit" class="edit">save</button></span>',
    text: '<span>{{text}}</edit>'
  }

  // for when you click on the span
  $("#theText").on('click', 'span', function() {
    var span = $(this)
    span.replaceWith(template.input.replace(/{{text}}/g, span.text()))
  })

  // when you click the button
  $("#theText").on('click', 'button', function() {
    var edit = $(this).parent()
    var newValue = edit.find('input').val()
    var origValue = edit.find('input').attr('orig')

    var value = confirm("Update your input as " + newValue + " ?") ? newValue : origValue

    edit.replaceWith(template.text.replace(/{{text}}/g, value))

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id="theText">Currently working in 
  
  <span>xyz*</span>for past <span>0-5 years*</span>.Studied Graduation from <span>ABC.</span>, 12th from <span>jnnj</span> with <span>80%</span>, 10th from <span>Bkbjkjnk</span> with <span>80%</span>

</h4>
```

Comment: @SarthakTuteja yes, sorry. I made an update to fix it

Answer (score 1):

```
your problem is solved u can see in snippet.
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bizcontent').click(function() {
      $('#myModal2').modal('toggle');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.editor', function() {
      $(".edit").show();
      $(".editor").hide();
      var edit = $("#edited").val();
    });

    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
      var edit = $("#edited").val();
      var ans = confirm("Update your input as " + edit + " ?");
      if (ans == true) {
        $(".edit").hide();
        $(".editor").replaceWith("<span class='editor'>" + edit + "</span>");
        $(".editor").show();

      } else {
        $(".editor").show();
        $(".edit").hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Currently working in <span class="editor">xyz*</span><span style= "display:none;" class="edit"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="edited" style="width:100px;z-index: 100;background: white;display: inline;"></span><button type="submit" id="submit" class="edit" style="display: none;">save</button>


          for past <span>0-5 years*</span>.Studied Graduation from <span>ABC.</span>, 12th from <span>jnnj</span> with <span>80%</span>, 10th from <span>Bkbjkjnk</span> with <span>80%</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that .editor once clicked and edited, was later not clickable, right?

The solution for that is:

```
 $("body").on('click', '.editor', function(){
      $(".edit").show();
      alert("hi");
      $(".editor").hide();
      var edit = $("#edited").val();
  });
```

Note: $("body").on('click', '.editor', ....);